# Controlling multiple servos with python and hardware needed(RPi 3)

Tags: python, pi-3, hardware, servo

I'm kind of new to the Raspberry Pi world and I've been researching for tutorials and how to's all around the web for software and hardware regarding a small project (RC car/robot).

What I've gathered so far is the type of motors and model I need, Python code (I think), basic wiring knowledge but I need to know a couple of things like:

- First of all, I read about using servoblaster to control multiple servos directly from the Pi itself, and;
- For the external power source, I read that powering the board from a power bank (6 V) will require a UBEC 5 V 3 A.

I'm trying to make a list with what to buy - can someone verify/refer me to any additional information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use servoblaster to send servo pulses.  There are alternatives like RPIO.GPIO (not RPi.GPIO) and my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) which are equally good.

A UBEC is a reasonable choice if you want to derive 5V from a battery pack.  Typically a UBEC will convert a wide range of voltages (say 7V-26V) to 5V.  If your battery pack is 6V check that it will be enough to work with the UBEC you choose.

Comment: I havent bought anything yet but those are the power bank and the ubec http://www.skroutz.gr/c/146/diafora-mikrohlektronika.html?from=catspan&keyphrase=ubec

Comment: http://www.skroutz.gr/s/9843153/GOLF-Tiger-804-10400mAh.html